# How to open and save a lot of child forms for reacting to parent form changes?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7, dfm

I have a parent form and thousands of child forms.
Each time I change something that affects the parent form's DFM, I would like to open and save the child forms in order to make sure the IDE adapts as conseguence of the changes applied to the parent form.

I've tried selecting all the forms and clicking "Open" from the right click popupmenu, but there are too many child forms and it raises the following error:

[image]

> Error creating form: System Error. Code: 1158.
>
> Il processo corrente ha utilizzato tutti gli handle degli oggetti di Window Manager resi disponibili dal sistema
>
> (translated) The current process used all Window Manager object's handles allowed by the system

I think that something like an "Open-Save-Close" action for multiple files could resolve the problem

Comment: DFMCheck has an open/close all forms: https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/

Comment: @UweRaabe Great! it's exactly what I was looking for, post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFMCheck has an open/close all forms: [idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck](https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/)